# "Questions about Datasets": Possible Exceptions?

Tags: discussion, data

By and large, I agree with the practice of closing questions which refer to specific datasets (**Matt Parker** very nicely summarizes the issue in his answer [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/486/suitable-venue-to-help-find-specific-statistical-data)).

Nevertheless, it's undeniable that some datasets hold a unique place in the realm of Data Analysis, transcending their particular (specialized) domain (e.g. Fisher's [Irises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set), Old Faithful data). Shouldn't these be treated differently?

I realize that it's hard to draw a line between these exceptional cases--perhaps an easy rule-of-thumb would be: "If it's built into **R** then it's ok."

Anyway, this is just something I was thinking about earlier and wanted to hear what you guys thought about it--as I think about it more I'll update this post accordingly.

[Note: I also think that **Cross Validated** could benefit overall if it even outright *encouraged* the use of these types of built-in datasets in the questions themselves. But that may be a whole different meta-post entirely...]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is someone really going to struggle to find the [Iris data-set](http://bit.ly/1ko278V) or whatever if they already know the name of it? The current wording of the off-topic reason is

> Questions about obtaining specific datasets are off-topic because they are too specialized and narrow in scope.

which I read as allowing requests for non-specific data-sets that can be used to make some statistical point.

So IMO

- Request for US macroeconomic indicators by year—off-topic.
- Request for dataset to test regression procedures with nearly collinear predictors—on-topic.
- Request for Longley data—lack of research.

Comment: Thanks for your response--in the process of reading different answers on **meta** I must've lost track of the specific wording of the off-topic reason (namely, that it only refers to "*obtaining*" datasets). In addition, I didn't realize that it *would* be acceptable to ask about obtaining certain *exemplary datasets* (as indicated by your second bullet point).

Comment: Well, that's my reading of "specific", plus the feeling that the intent's to rule out "Where can I get data on $X$?" questions, which are better suited to CV sites covering $X$.

Comment: I meant "SE sites covering $X$" of course. Perhaps also worth pointing out that there's [Locating freely available data samples](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples), to avoid duplicates of the general "Where can I find data to practise on?" question.

Comment: There's also http://opendata.stackexchange.com (which like any big haystack is not easy to search).